# Using Web.Api to asynchronously log errors for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a legacy logging DLL that logs errors into a database.  Instead of consuming the DLL within each application in our environment, we would like to make web calls to log errors.

I have built up a web.api app that will log errors into a database. When tested with POSTMAN it works as advertised.

I have added a class within a demo MVC app and wired up one of my constructors to execute a log command, but the call not only does not make it to my web.api, but fiddler does not show a call even being made.

Any input on making this actually run would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

Logging Utility Called within Web.API

```
public class Utilities
{
    public void LogException(string exceptionMessage, string stackTrace, string appCode, string runMode, int entityId, int itmsUserID, string updateBy, string path, string method)
    {
        ErrorLog.Entry _error = new ErrorLog.Entry();
        _error.ErrorMessage = exceptionMessage;
        _error.StackTrace = stackTrace;
        _error.AppCode = appCode;
        _error.Path = path;
        _error.Method = method;
        _error.UpdateBy = updateBy;
        _error.RunMode = runMode;
        _error.EntityID = entityId;
        //_error.Server = server;   server will have to be changed to accept a setter
        _error.ITMSUserID = CommonFunctions.Get_ITMSUserID(updateBy);
        _error.Save();
    }
}
```

Web.API

```
    // POST: api/ErrorLog
    public void Post([FromBody]ErrorLogEntryDTO item)
    {
        var utils = new Utilities();

        utils.LogException(item.ErrorMessage, item.StackTrace, item.AppCode, item.RunMode, item.EntityID, item.ITMSUserID, item.UpdateBy, item.Path, item.Method);
    }
```

MVC Controller Code

```
    // GET: BillingRules/Create
    public virtual ActionResult CauseHandledError()
    {
        try
        {

            throw new Exception("Handled exception test");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var utils = new Utilities();
            utils.LogException(ex, "system", MVC.BillingRules.Name, MVC.BillingRules.ActionNames.CauseHandledError);
        }
        return RedirectToAction(MVC.BillingRules.ActionNames.Index, MVC.BillingRules.Name);
    }
```

Utilities Code within MVC App

```
    public void LogException(Exception exception, string updateBy, string path, string method)
    {
        try
        {
            var itmsUserID = CommonFunctions.Get_ITMSUserID(updateBy);

            var errorDTO = new ErrorLogEntryDTO();
            errorDTO.ITMSUserID = itmsUserID;
            errorDTO.AppCode = _appCode.Value;
            errorDTO.ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
            errorDTO.StackTrace = exception.StackTrace;
            errorDTO.Path = path;
            errorDTO.Method = method;
            errorDTO.UpdateBy = updateBy;

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52316");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ErrorLog", errorDTO).Result; //ContinueWith(readTask => client.Dispose()); // 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var myError = ex;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure calling `.Result` in this instance does not immediately invoke the `PostAsJsonAsync` method.  Because you're not doing anything with the Result, it never actually executes. Since it doesn't appear you care about the response, you should be able to use:

```
client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ErrorLog", errorDTO).Wait();
```

Comment: You are correct in that we are wanting to totally disregard, or ignore, the response.  Ideally we call the logger and move on with our processes, skipping the results and the timelag in waiting for them.

Comment: Totally get what you're after. If it's possible for you to use async/await, then you could await client.PostAsJsonAsync(...), but also add a ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false) which would offload the Post and not be concerned with rejoining the original context.

Answer (score 0):

I think `.Result` invokes the `PostAsJsonAsync` call. You are waiting for the respsonse, so the call must be finished after this line. Regardless if you use the Result or not.

You can remove the `[FromBody]` attribute, because the complex type is per default read from the body.

And I can't reproduce your issue. I've created a new Web API project and a new console project. In the Web API I've changed the post of the valuescontroller to yours.
In the console project I'm yousing your `LogException()` method from the MVC app.
It hits my web api app.
Are both in the same host or in different hosts?

Edit:
To make your logging async you can use fire-and-forget with `Task.Run()` but it depends on the application you have. In ASP.Net `Task.Run()` is an anti-pattern according to [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).